# JQuery inside function call another function = undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to call another function before body, but how?

The system shows me the error `undefined function myx`

I only can add code after body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    function myx() {
        alert("omg");
    };
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("mytest").click(function(){
        myx();
    });
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="mytest">Check</a>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure its impossible to get at `myx` without editing the head. Is duplicating `myx` in your body script an option?

Comment: @PHPglue The `.ready()` event's the exception. The argument is instead a reference to `jQuery` as described under "[*Aliasing the jQuery Namespace*](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)"

Answer (score 0):

That function is out of scope. You need to define the function outside the jQuery callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myx() {
        alert("omg");
    };
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mytest").click(function(){
        myx();
    });
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="mytest">Check</a>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I know, but as I said, I can only add code after body, I can't edit head code. any idea ?

Comment: Then you really have two problems.

Answer (score -1):

Use external JavaScript, so it's cached into the Browser Memory, so when your Client visits again it will load faster. Then look at this:

```
// wrapper is same as $(document).ready() with no-conflict
jQuery(function($){
// should be defined once everything has loaded
function myx(){
  // never use alert except to test
  alert('OMG!');
}
// passing a function name like a var is the same as Anonymous function
$('#mytest').click(myx);
});
// Ignoring outer wrapper to save indenting - indent everything further
```

The important thing is that `myx` should be defined after everything has loaded.

You don't have to, but it's a best practice to use external JavaScript and put the `<script>` tags in the `<head>`, setting both `<script type='text/javascript' src='yourUrl.js'></script>` to be W3C Compliant. Additionally, technologically the `document.body` may not be available to some older Browsers if your `<script>` tags are defined in the `<body>`, as HTML must be defined before JavaScript is able to get it, which is why you use the Anonymous function inside of `jQuery()` (same as $(document).ready() or the JavaScript onload Event). Then you get the HTML with JavaScript because those Elements are available `onload`.