# JQuery Jcrop without function to resize select size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Update

I think I solved my problem, but I want to know any better way ?

My solution is call Jcrop function again, like this

```
$('#target').Jcrop({
    setSelect: [100,100,200,200]
});
```

OLD =======================================================================

As we know Jcrop have setSelect this function to set select size

But if I can't use that function, how can I do the same thing ?
(check here [JQuery inside function call another function = undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557376/jquery-inside-function-call-another-function-undefined))

I tried this code I wrote, but when I drag select area, that will auto resize back, I'm not sure why ?

Can someone help ? thanks a lot

JCrop link
http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Download.html

My code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello World | Jcrop Demo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){

    // How easy is this??
    $('#target').Jcrop();

  });

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_files/demos.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="sp_box">
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#my_fit").click(function(){
            $(".jcrop-holder div:first").css({"width":"180", "height":"180"});

        });
    });
    </script>
    <a href="#" id="my_fit">Fit Size Here</a>
</div>
<img src="demo_files/sago.jpg" id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

As you already wrote in your edited post, you can reinitialize the plugin in the body section of your document.

I did a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qegtuw5e/) with centered crop area. I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but it works.

Edit end

---

Deprecated answer:

Unfortunately I can't comment and I'm unsure what you wanna do. But why not initialize the jcrop widget with the options maxSize and aspectRatio like this?

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#target').Jcrop({
         aspectRatio: 1,
         maxSize: [180, 180]
    });
});
```

Comment: because I can only add code after body, I can't edit head code, but I think we are the same way (ps: I just want to add some button like (fit to 100x100, fit to 200x200... etc)

Comment: I haven't figured that out, I'm sorry. But regarding your buttons for different sizes, I think that example on the page is pretty much what you need? http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler

Comment: @plzhelp Added a jsfiddle with buttons like you mentioned